# Why does Javascript console.log displays object's value ahead of time in this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox, logging, console.log

I'll start with the code:

```
var x = {list: [1, 2, 3], num: 4};
console.log(x);
function asd(x) {
    x.list[0] = 4;
    return x;
}

console.log(x);
asd(x);
console.log(x);
```

At the firefox console, the result was this:

```
list: Array [ 4, 2, 3 ]
num: 4

list: Array [ 4, 2, 3 ]
num: 4

list: Array [ 4, 2, 3 ]
num: 4
```

How can that be? Shouldn't it be [1, 2, 3] first, and then [1, 2, 3], and only then [4, 3, 2]? What happened here?

Comment: Object reference in console.log() is hoisted.

Comment: It is the same question, just print it like this: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));` and you'll realize that :)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Indeed it is. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Comment: Of course, if your Object isn't proper JSON you'll want to make a recursive copy function.

Comment: The Chrome bug was fixed years ago and at the time, Firefox didn't have the issue. But, looks like it might have a similar issue now. It isn't a scope issue, whether x is scoped to the function (it is) or not wouldn't affect expected output.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Chrome's still bugged, just try OP code.